# AWS import vmdk java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to import the vmdk to AWS EC2, but there seems to be no good java API documentation.

I have come across below flow, which should work,

```
    DiskImageDetail id = new DiskImageDetail();
    id.setFormat(DiskImageFormat.VMDK);
    // id.setImportManifestUrl(importManifestUrl)

    // TODO: set to 10GB e.g.
    id.setBytes(80000000000L);

    VolumeDetail volume = new VolumeDetail();
    volume.setSize(80000000000L);

    DiskImage i = new DiskImage();
    i.setImage(id);
    i.setVolume(volume);
    i.setDescription("disk image");

    List<DiskImage> listImages = new ArrayList<DiskImage>();
    listImages.add(i);

    ImportInstanceLaunchSpecification ls = new ImportInstanceLaunchSpecification();

    ImportInstanceRequest ir = new ImportInstanceRequest();
    ir.setDescription("Test");
    ir.setDiskImages(listImages);
    ir.setRequestCredentials(Connection.getAWSCredentials());
    // ir.setGeneralProgressListener()
    ir.setLaunchSpecification(ls);


    // Some code to set 
    ImportVolumeRequest ivr = new ImportVolumeRequest();
    //ivr.setSomeData();


    AmazonEC2 ec2 = // set some connection 
    ec2.importInstance(ir);
    ec2.importVolume(ivr);
```

But I am not sure about what values to pass, there's no sample code as well !

It can be done with the cmdlets but with Java I don't see anything hopeful.

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello there, can someone please help on this ?

Comment: How to pass the vmdk file path? Thanks